# ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module while using Netlify lambda functions with dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, netlify

[image]

I'm trying to use netlify and its lambda function feature to run a node function with dependencies. Based on https://css-tricks.com/using-netlify-forms-and-netlify-functions-to-build-an-email-sign-up-widget/ , I have in my functions/submission-created.js:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = async event => {

    const email = JSON.parse(event.body).payload.EMAIL
    const asking = JSON.parse(event.body).payload.ASKING
    console.log(`Recieved a submission: ${email}`)
    ....
```

When I look under my netlify websites functions tab (secreenshot above) , I see:

```
11:40:35 PM: 2020-12-02T04:40:35.092Z   undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/submission-created.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'","Require stack:","- /var/task/submission-created.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- /var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
```

my package.json (after running npm init):

```
{
"name": "site",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
  "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
}
 }
```

The package structure looks like:

[image]

here is the repo :

```
https://github.com/kc1/test2
```

I've tried putting the node modules folder and package.json in multiple places and repushing the repo, but I'm still getting the error above. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

please see [Netlify: No build command found, continuing to publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204543/netlify-no-build-command-found-continuing-to-publishing) for new info on build process

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one `package.json` in the `base directory`. If that does not work then try to delete `package-lock.json` and try again. Do not push the `node_modules` folder since `Netlify` runs `npm install`.

> If your build requires any JavaScript dependencies, you must list
> these in a package.json file saved in the site's base directory in
> your repository.
>
> ...
>
> By default, if your site's base directory does not include a yarn.lock
> file (more information below), we will run npm install to install the
> dependencies listed in your package.json file.

https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/#javascript-dependencies

https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#definitions

If it still does not work and is an acceptable solution you could also download the script and import it locally.

```
require('./fetch.min.js')
```

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-fetch@2.6.1/browser.min.js

If this does not work I would try to `Run a local development environment` for better debugging and see what packages you actually get in the production environment.

https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#run-a-local-development-environment

The last thing that I can think of is to check if `Node.js` And `Require()` can find `node_modules` but it is a real long shot:

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm

Comment: Please see edit. I've tried most of the steps you recommended, but I'm now thinking I've messed up build process even without errors

Comment: @user1592380 Different question altogether but I hope the answer I provided there could work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of these options without success. Eventually I ended up deleting the site and rebuilding it from my github repo, this time without the node modules. It built and now I can use npm modules

Answer (score 1):

I think there's lots of reason for this error, I got it today and tried some solutions from [Error: Cannot find module ‘node-fetch’” when deploying function](https://community.netlify.com/t/error-cannot-find-module-node-fetch-when-deploying-function/7254/9);[Netlify Functions Can't find module](https://community.netlify.com/t/netlify-functions-cant-find-module/27634); and [Cannot use node-fetch in lambda function](https://community.netlify.com/t/cannot-use-node-fetch-in-lambda-function/18439)

- Installing dependencies in project root
- Installing deps in functions specific folder e.g. having `functions/testfunc/package.json` and changing command in `netlify.toml` to `cd functions/testfunc && npm install && cd ../../ && npm build`
- Changing const `fetch = require('node-fetch')` to:

  - `const fetch = require('node-fetch').default`
  - `const fetch = request('node-fetch').default`
- Adding `node-fetch`'s peer dependency `encoding`

However, none of these things worked. I then tried seeing if copying the [Fetch](https://functions.netlify.com/playground/#fetch) example from Netlify functions playground would work and it did. The issue was that I had a variable in my function called `static`

```
const static = ['/blog', '/about', '/'];
```

For some reason having a variable called **static** causes

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'
```

I don't know why but changing this to something else fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and fixed it by deleting the site, removing node_modules from my repo, and starting over with a new site. I tried to recreate the issue to see if removing node_modules alone would fix it however I didn't run into the same problem when I recreated it.