# Netlify,toml vs package.json in Netlify build process

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, netlify

I'm trying to use netlify and its lambda function feature to run a node function . Based on https://css-tricks.com/using-netlify-forms-and-netlify-functions-to-build-an-email-sign-up-widget/ .

I'm having trouble getting node modules to work (see [ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module while using Netlify lambda functions with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134613/importmoduleerror-errormessageerror-cannot-find-module-while-using-netlify))

Currently my netlify.toml has only the following:

```
[build]
  command = "npm install && npm run build"
  functions = "./functions"
```

and my package.json:

```
"name": "test2",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "build": "npm run build"
},
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git+https://github.com/kc1/test2.git"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"bugs": {
  "url": "https://github.com/kc1/test2/issues"
} ,
"homepage": "https://github.com/kc1/test2#readme",
"dependencies": {
  "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
  "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
}
}
```

What is the relationship between package.json and netlify.toml in the netlify build process (I'm primarily a python developer and fairly new to node ) ?

Comment: The package.json script `"build": "npm run build"` will call itself in an infinite loop

Comment: Yes , that's what happened. (https://app.netlify.com/sites/inspiring-ardinghelli-4a4da5/deploys/5fd119b05df9b10007467752). Do I need it at all given "1:38:57 PM: Executing user command: npm install && npm run build" - which I assume comes from the toml file?
"

Comment: from what I can see here the toml file is telling the computer to run `npm run build` and the package.json file is telling the computer to run `npm run build` resulting in an infinite loop. What you need to do is actually run something or disable the command... I can't know what to run as I don't know anything about your project

Comment: I'm assuming you do have to run a build but what that command is I can't know. Could be a CRA build command or a babel build or something entirely different